# Split string into variables based off of values

Tags: php

I have the following PHP code and would like to split the string into separate variables:

```
$names = "login1,login2,login3,login4,...loginN";
```

Example result:

```
$login1 = "login1";

$login2 = "login2";

$login3 = "login3";

$login4 = "login4";
```

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Use [explode](http://php.net/explode).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
foreach (explode(',', $names) as $name) {
    $$name = $name;
}
```

But really, why in the world do you want to do this?

Comment: Thats really new to me and really weird syntax.

Comment: [Variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) are?

Comment: +1 for answer, but also agree with the questioning of "Why?" -- wouldn't an array be better?

Comment: // Example 1
$pizza  = "piece1 piece2 piece3 piece4 piece5 piece6";
$pieces = explode(" ", $pizza);
echo $pieces[0]; // piece1
echo $pieces[1]; // piece2

in this script how to echo all what in $pizza

like

echo $pieces[0];
echo $pieces[1];
echo $pieces[2];
...

Comment: @Narek Use `foreach`! In my example I'm showing you how to use it. Just `echo $name` instead of assigning it.

Comment: tyvm you helped me you can close this topic

Answer (score 0):

If a more flexible extraction was needed then you could utilize regular expressions via [preg_split()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php):

```
foreach(preg_split('/,/', $names) as $login){
    $$login = $login;
};
```